# Searching for a word that best fits in the context “Der Schüler —— eine Lernvereinbarung.”

Tags: verb, single-word-request

I can’t think of a verb that fits well in the sentence

> Der Schüler ???? eine Lernvereinbarung

The two words I could think of were *bekommen* and *erhalten*, d.h.

> Der Schüler bekommt eine Lernvereinbarung.
>
> Der Schüler erhält eine Lernvereinbarung.

However both sound slightly odd to my ears and I was wondering if there was another verb that fits better in this context.

Comment: Context, please...

Comment: @Stephie The full sentence will be something like 'Ich bin damit einverstanden, dass mein Sohn eine Lernvereinbarung ----.'

Comment: With whom? (And: any reason we don't discuss this in German? Not that English bothers me...) And a bit more background story wouldn't be bad either.

Comment: Deutsch geht natürlich auch, ich hab bloß gerade nur eine englische Tastatur parat und es nervt, mit der auf Deutsch zu schreiben.

Mehr Kontext kann ich glaube ich nicht geben. Das "ich" in dem Satz ist ein Elternteil des Schülers.. Die Lernvereinbarung wird beantragt.

Comment: Das hier ist ein *Deutsch*-Forum. Wenn du fließend Deutsch sprichst, solltest du deine Fragen bitte auch in dieser Sprache formulieren. Englisch ist natürlich auch erlaubt, aber wenn du beide Sprachen sprichst, solltest du Deutsch den Vorzug geben. http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-the-questions-be-written-in/829#829

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ach das habe ich gar nicht gewusst...ich war schon lange nicht auf german.stackexchange.com und habe vorhin immer den Eindruck gehabt, dass die meisten Fragen auf Englisch gestellt wurden. Gut zu wissen

Comment: Es gibt hier drei Benutzergruppen: 1) Englische Muttersprachler 2) Deutschsprachige, die glauben, man müsse in einem Deutsch-Forum eine Fremdsprache verwenden 3) Deutschsprachige, die auf Deutsch schreiben. Leider ist die Gruppe 3 kleiner als die beiden anderen Gruppen zusammen, daher entstehen die meisten Fragen in englischer Sprache. Das weckt offenbar bei vielen Deutschsprachigen den Eindruck, sie müssten eine Fremdsprache verwenden, was die Gruppe 2 wachsen lässt, und auf diese Weise zu einer unerwünschten Rückkopplung führt.

Comment: Faustregel für Fragen: Wenn du einigermaßen gut Deutsch sprichst, dann schreibe hier auf Deutsch. Wenn dein Deutsch zu schlecht ist, solltest du Englisch schrieben. Andere Sprachen sind hier nicht erlaubt. Faustregel für Antworten: Antworte in der Sprache, in der die Frage gestellt wurde.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Alles klar.

Comment: Wenn es wirklich eine _Vereinbarung_ ist, kann man diese nur abschließen, oder meinetwegen unterschreiben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *Vereinbarung* (= agreement) is typically something bilateral, not one-sided.

So you would

> eine Lernvereinbarung *eingehen*
>   eine L. *abschließen*
>   eine L. treffen
>   eine L. *vereinbaren* (ok, that’s a bit redundant)

If on the other hand a student would

> eine Lernvereinbarung *bekommen* (or similar)
>   The element of mutuality is missing: Neither semantically nor paedagogically a useful aproach.

And of course if the parents’ agreement is required, they can be

> … einverstanden, dass mein Kind eine L. eingeht.

If you don’t want the child’s consent, you would need to dump the *-vereinbarung* and use *-plan* or similar instead, that can be unilateral: Teacher tells child to follow a given plan.

Comment: Aha! jetzt kann ich einsehen, wieso mehr Kontext nötig war. `eingehen` war das Wort, das ich suchte. Danke

Comment: @aras: Mehr Kontext kann nie falsch sein. Selbst dann nicht, wenn man meint, bereits alles gesagt zu haben, was man für die Beantwortung einer Frage für notwendig hält.

Answer (score 3):

A *Vereinbarung* is a kind of contract. You can not *get* or *receive* a contract. But you can:

- unterzeichnen (sign):

  > Der Schüler **unterzeichnet** eine Lernvereinbarung.
  >   The student **signs** a learning agreement.
- abschließen (enter)

  > Der Schüler **schließt** eine Lernvereinbarung **ab**.
  >   The student **enters into** a learning agreement.

If the agreement already exists, and the student joins it, you can also say:

- beitreten (join)

  > Der Schüler **tritt** einer Lernvereinbarung **bei**.
  >   The student **joins** a learning agreement.